# installing a non-PyPi package into virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-packaging

I am new to Python so please be patient with me. I am installing all the usual packages via pip into a virtual environment with no problem. But then there are external packages that I am grabbing from github and my own library package lib. I want to add these to my project and I want to maintain versioning so I know when to update. All I see as I research is code like

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
sys.path.append(current_path)
```

That adds the package directory to the path. There are also examples of import statements with relative paths.

Shouldn't these non-pip packages be installed straight into the virtual environment with proper versioning? How do I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean saying "non-pip packages"? Python packages that are not published at PyPI? Or non-python libraries?

Comment: Packages on PyPi. I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that since pip supports installation from a version control system, see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).

This assumes that the package you wish to install has a setup.py file.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git
```

### Git

(Mostly extraction form [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support))

Pip supports cloning over `git`, `git+http`, `git+https`, `git+ssh`, `git+git` and `git+file`.

```
[-e] git://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
[-e] git+http://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
[-e] git+https://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
[-e] git+ssh://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
[-e] git+git://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
[-e] git+file://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
-e git+git@git.myproject.org:MyProject#egg=MyProject
```

You can also ask to install from a specific branch, commit hash, or tag name if you want a beta version or a branch that is targeted to your specific distribution etc by using `@` and passing over the name of the branch/commit hash/tag name:

Branch:

```
[-e] git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject
```

Commit Has:

```
[-e] git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#egg=MyProject
```

Tag:

```
git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@v1.0#egg=MyProject
```

### Here is a real-world use-case (Git):

Let's say that we wish to install the following Python package that is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example).

Simply I will run:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git
```

And here is the result:

```
(test) pc-207-126:Desktop rafael$ pip install git+git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git
  Cloning git://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git to /private/var/folders/c_/8qcnm5sj3kg7_f887qv473tm0000gn/T/pip-mx1vcsod-build
Collecting numpy (from python-package-example==0.1)
  Downloading numpy-1.14.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (4.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.7MB 305kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy, python-package-example
  Running setup.py install for python-package-example ... done
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.1 python-package-example-0.1
```

If I now run `pip freeze` to see if the package was installed:

```
(test) pc-207-126:Desktop rafael$ pip freeze
numpy==1.14.1
python-package-example==0.1
```

As you can see the installation was successful and has also installed some dependencies of the Python-Package-Example (i.e numpy).

**Note:** github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git uses Python 2 syntax. For an example containing Python 3 syntax, see https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod. The difference is in the import syntax in **init**, python 2 uses 'import somePython' while python 3 uses 'from . import somePython'